# Rows to columns in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Below is my output from normalizer

```
ID  VALUE   GCID

3   12345     1

3   123456    2

3   1234      3

3   IG        4

3   5/5/2015  5

3   5/10/2015 6

4    34567    1

4   456789    2

4   23467     3

4   IG        4

4   5/5/2015  5

4   5/10/2015 6
```

How do I obtain the below output?

```
ID  VALUE   GCID    DATE1   DATE2

3   12345   1   5/5/2015    5/10/2015

3   123456  2   5/5/2015    5/10/2015

3   1234    3   5/5/2015    5/10/2015

4   34567    1  5/5/2015    5/10/2015

4   456789   2  5/5/2015    5/10/2015

4   23467    3  5/5/2015    5/10/2015
```

Comment: Why are you normalizing if you want to denormalize?

Comment: Can you please provide sample source data?